# DIV partition with CSS

Tags: css, html

I got a problem with my DIV partition. I want this:
[image]

But i found no solution. Can anybody help me?

With this solution, the all container are on the left and not centered.

```
#logo-text{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}

#image{
 float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have not given any examples of what you have tried, i'd like to give you this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LRffh/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="lineLeft">

        <div id="boxOne">box one</div>
        <div id="boxTwo">box two</div>

    </div>
    <div id="lineRight">

        <div id="image">image</div>

    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 1px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
}

#lineLeft, #lineRight {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
}

#lineLeft {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#boxOne, #boxTwo, #image {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}

#lineLeft div, #lineRight div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='continer'>
    <div class='logo'></div>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <div class='text'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.continer {
    width:500px;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
    height:400px;
}

.logo {
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ddd;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.text {
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ddd;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.image {
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ddd;
    height:340px;
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74T9J/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#wrapper
{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:1000px;
        }
#side
{
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px;
    width:350px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;

        }
#first
{
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px;
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
        }
#Second
{
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px;
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
        }
#content
{
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px;
    width:650px;
    height:600px;
    float:right;
    background-color:green;
        }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="side">
        <div id="first"></div>
        <div id="Second"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps
http://jsfiddle.net/LSsMc/48/

Answer (score 0):

Here's **[another take on the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr5r7/)**

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='table'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='cell'></div>    
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='cell'></div>    
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'></div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    position:fixed;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:50%;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a container class for example who contains all the childs elements, to center the content.

html part :

```
<div class="container">
<div id="left">
    <div id="logo-text"></div>
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

css part :

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Left part */
#left {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

#logo-text {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#text {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

/* Right part */
#right {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}

#image {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/LSZfH/1/